# unable to access drive

Tags: permissions, home-directory

I am new to the Ubuntu family, maybe a week, and already now I have got an error. 
The error is that I cannot access my own drive which is named computer here. The images below explain the story.

how can I get back my rights ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not an error. [@the_Seppi's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/528807/283843) explains that.

Answer (score 4):

`/home` is not your home folder, neither is `/`. These directories are intended to belong to root, and so it does on your system.

Your home folder is *inside* `/home`, i.e. `/home/yourusername`. This subfolder belongs to you, but not its parent `home`. Nearly everything outside your home folder doesn't belong to you only to protect the system. If every user and every program had access to the whole file system, the system may break pretty fast.

So everything's fine, you're just searching at the wrong place. If you indeed need to access these directories (which you shouldn't as a mere user), start nautilus with `gksudo nautilus` to gain root access.